# PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Does not work with Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

Im having issues getting -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to work with cmdlet 'Get-ADUser'

This doesn't work, the error is displayed with or without -ErrorAction?

```
  get-aduser "JSmith" -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  if ($Err){write-host "This is an error!!!!"}
```

This works (No error is display and silently continues, under the same conditions?

```
 get-childitem z: -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 if ($Err){write-host "This is an error!!!!"}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The get is actually performed at the DC by the gateway service, and the error handling doesn't work quite the same.  Fortunately Try/Catch does work:

```
Try { get-aduser "JSmith" } 
  Catch { write-host "This is an error!!!!" }
```

Comment: FYI: Changing to just `catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] ` will ensure that only identity not found exceptions are caught.  ps. I've written a proxy function to return null instead of throwing exceptions to avoid having to add try/catch blocks where this cmdlet's used frequently.  Code's in a post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205808/powershell-proxy-function-adding-exception-handling (not great, but it does the job).

Comment: @JohnLBevan - you can also avoid it by using an explicit filter.

Comment: @mjolinor what is DC?

Comment: @ameliapond DC = domain controller

Answer (score 12):

What mjolinor is saying about the explicit filter is the following works:

```
$Sam = "JSmith"

$userObj = get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $Sam} -erroraction silentlycontinue
```

`$userObj` will be null if the user is not found.  This allows the code to address the not found condition with out using the try/catch.