# Create New-AdUser IsValid parameter

Tags: powershell

I've got a function that checks AD before attempting to "choose" a username; it'll start by assuming first initial+last name, and see if that's already in AD.

If it is, it'll add letters from the first name until it finds an unused username. If it exhausts all letters in the first name, it'll tack an incrementing number on the end (i.e. jdoe, jodoe, johdoe, johndoe, johndoe1, johndoe2, etc.):

Note: this assumes you have the first name as `$FirstName` and the last name as `$LastName`

When attempting to run script then I got the following the error message:

> Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'JDoe' under: >'DC=contoso,DC=com'.
>   At line:18 char:31
>   +         $usernameExists = Get-ADUser <<<<  $username -ErrorAction >SilentlyContinue | format-wide IsValid
>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (JDoe:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], >ADIdentityNotFoundException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'JDoe' >under: >'DC=contoso,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
>   Setting username as JDoe

I am assuming there is a problem related to the `IsValid` parameter?

```
$firstname_auto = $firstname.ToLower()
$lastname_auto = $lastname.ToLower()

$FirstNameLength = ($firstname_auto | Measure-Object -Character).Characters
$letterCount = 0
$username = ''

#Try to spell out the entire first name until we can get a unique username
do {
    $letterCount++
    $usernameExists = $false
    $username = "$($firstname_auto.Substring(0,$letterCount))$($lastname_auto)"
    $usernameExists = Get-ADUser $username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | format-wide IsValid
    if ($usernameExists -eq $true) {
        Write-Verbose "$username exists in AD. Trying again."
    }
} until (($usernameExists -eq $false) -OR ($letterCount -eq $FirstNameLength))

#If we've used all the letters in the first name, and the username still isn't unique,
#start counting until we find one that is.
if ($usernameExists -eq $true) {
    $usernameNumber = 0
    Write-Verbose "Exhausted all non-numeric options! Trying with numbers."
    do {
        $usernameNumber++
        $usernameExists = $false
        $username = "$($firstname_auto.Substring(0,$letterCount))$lastname_auto$usernameNumber"
        $usernameExists = Get-ADUser $username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | format-wide IsValid
        if ($usernameExists -eq $true) {
            Write-Verbose "$username already exists in AD. Trying again."
        }
    } until ($usernameExists -eq $false)
}

Write-host "Setting username as $username" -foregroundcolor Green
```

Comment: Looks like the AD PowerShell Tools aren't ether, installed or loaded as your script cannot find the get `Get-ADUser` command in any valid module. Try running `import-module activedirectory` and if you get an error you will need to [install the RSAT tools](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/)

Comment: I have updated my error message. BTW already installed ActiveDirectory module.

Comment: The AD cmdlets still show the error even with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000356/powershell-erroraction-silentlycontinue-does-not-work-with-get-aduser) have details on this. That error message can be ignored, and it just means that `JDoe` doesn't exist.

Comment: I got it man. So I assuming I have to use  try / catch block to avoid this error message. Could you please supply me  sample line? thanks again

Comment: `try { $usernameExists = Get-ADUser $username } catch {Write-Verbose "Username: $username not found in AD"}`