# How to catch error from Remove-Item and emit a warning instead?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, azure-devops

In a post-deployment script used in a continuous integration pipeline (Azure DevOps), I'm removing old files.

Basically, it's a PowerShell script that removes every release folder but the current one in the deployment directory.

Sometimes, the Remove-Item fails for some reason (old file still opened by someone one the deplyoment machine, for instance)

It's not a big deal. I don't want an error saying my whole deployment failed because of this. However, I want a warning, so I'm aware that it happened.

For instance (MCVE):

```
Remove-Item INEXISTENT_FILE
```

**Problem** : it causes an error.

---

Attempt 1 :

```
Remove-Item INEXISTENT_FILE -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

**Problem** : It removes the Error completely, that's not what I want (I want a warning)

---

Attempt 2 : I tried to use ErrorVariable as recommended here : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/erroraction-and-errorvariable/

```
Remove-Item INEXISTENT_FILE -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable $removeItemError
if ($removeItemError) {
    Write-Warning "Warning, something failed!"
}
```

**Problem** : it doesn't work, it doesn't show the `if` part. If I remove "SilentlyContinue" error action, it just emits an error, and in any case never goes into the `if` part.

---

Attempt 3 : I tried to use also Try Catch block as proposed here : [PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Does not work with Get-ADUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000356/powershell-erroraction-silentlycontinue-does-not-work-with-get-aduser)

```
Try {
    Remove-Item INEXISTENT_FILE
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Warning, something failed!"
}
```

**Problem** : it never goes into the catch block either (!?)

---

Anyone has another option to show a warning instead of an error if Remove-Item fails ?

Comment: Attempt 2 DOES work, once you've fixed a minor (but fatal) error: `-ErrorVariable` is defined WITHOUT the `$` prefix. Just the variable name is expected like so: `-ErrorAction removeItemError` . Additionally, you can use a '+' prefix and errors will be _added_ to that variable. You then use it normally in the IF check: `$removeItemError` and voilà: you've been warned!

Comment: @Herve Very good to know, learned something on Powershell. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error produced by `Remove-Item` is considered 'non-terminating', which means that it is ignored by 'try/catch'.  To force it to become 'visible' to 'try/catch' use the `ErrorAction` parameter:

`Remove-Item INEXISTENT_FILE -ErrorAction Stop`

Alternatively, you can change this at the script level (i.e. for all subsequent commands) like this:

`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

The error message can be retrieved using `$_.Exception.Message` or `$error[0]`

Comment: It works indeed ! The ErrorVariable is not working, though, do you know if I can get the actual error emssage ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the error message once inside the `catch` block?  The exception details are stored in the `$_` variable in that case.  You could try adding to your warning like this: `Write-Warning "Warning, something failed: $($_.Exception.Message)"`

Comment: Thank you, indeed. I also incidentally checked that I can get them from the predefined `$error[0]` as well.