# How to create bulk users in Active Directory into specific OU

Tags: powershell

i want to create AD users in bulk with a csv file. i got some code from the internet, which is working fine. now there is one last thing missing. i would like to create a organization unit before running the script. all users which the script creates should automatically be created and the prior created OU.

{

```
$Import = Import-CSV ".\users.csv" -Delimiter ";"
$OU = "OU=User,OU=Office,DC=Company,DC=com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Initpass" -AsPlainText -Force
    
    foreach ($user in $Import) {
      New-ADUser -Name $user.SamAccountName -GivenName $user.GivenName -Surname $user.Surname -Path $OU -AccountPassword $Password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -Enabled $True -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Import = Import-CSV ".\users.csv" -Delimiter ";"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Initpass" -AsPlainText -Force
    
foreach ($user in $Import) {
  # A try-catch statement is used here, if an error is returned from Get-ADOrganisationUnit then it will run the code in the Catch segment.
  try {
    # Try to get info on this OU. If it exists then it will output information, which we then delete by piping into Out-Null.
    # If it fails, it will create an error and trigger the Catch statement.
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $user.OU -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
  }
  catch {
    # Here in the catch statement we create the OU based on the $user.OU value.
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit $user.OU
  }
  # This code is the same, except the path has been replaced with $User.OU.
  New-ADUser -Name $user.SamAccountName -GivenName $user.GivenName -Surname $user.Surname -Path $User.OU -AccountPassword $($User.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -Enabled $True -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName
}
```

I've used a Try-Catch statement here instead of an IF Statement, this is just because of the [weird way the Get-AD Commandlets handle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000462/22794052), which makes it difficult to hide them using the normal method of the ErrorPreference variable.

I've assumed that your target OU is also in your users.csv and can be referenced through `$User.OU`, if not you just need to update the variable name.

Comment: To make sure the code will enter the `catch` block also on non-terminating errors, append `-ErrorAction Stop` to the Get-ADOrganizationalUnit call inside the `try` block

Comment: hello hugeatwork, thank you very much for the great solution. just one more thing. giving the same password for all created users is not really a good idea. so i thought about to add one column more in the csv file which provides a individual password for each user. i would then modify the code of the password part like this -AccountPassword $User.Password. is this possible and if yes how could the password of the csv be converted to secure string ?  thank you for your help, san

Comment: @sanjacob I've edited my answer, it now includes your unique password. You just need to swap out the password variable for your CSV entry variable while piping it into `ConvertTo-SecureString`, [the `-Force` and `-AsPlainText` switches are needed here because the password is not encrypted in your CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: @HugoAtWork thank you very much. is there a reason why you put the -UserPrincipalName after the pipe ? i just want to understand the logic that's why i ask. i suppose i could add even more details like emaila address if i want to the code/csv , by extending the code with -EmailAddress $user.EmailAddress ? this would then be set as primary mail address for the users, correct ?

Comment: @sanjacob yes that would work fine. There's no reason for the placement of the pipe, it only affects what's inside the `$()` symbols here, this ensures only the `$user.password` is piped into `ConvertTo-SecureString`

Comment: @HugoAtWork i think i understood the logic . thank you very much for the code. i will make some adds and then test a little bit around. have a great day